# Как вывести посты в Wordpress с разными контейнерами

Tags: wordpress

Мне нужно правильно построить цикл, для вывода постов
Идея такая:
Есть два контейнера latest_post и all_posts.

Открываем latest_post
в него помещаем один item_post
Закрываем контейнер latest_post
Открываем контейнер all_posts
в него помещаем шесть item_post

Открываем latest_post
в него помещаем один item_post
Закрываем контейнер latest_post
Открываем контейнер all_posts
в него помещаем шесть item_post
Закрываем контейнер item_post

итд

```
<?php 

                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'publish' => true,
                    );

                    query_posts($args);

                    if (have_posts()) : ?>

                    <?php
                        $i = 0;
                    ?>

                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php
                        $i++;
                        if ($i > 7) {
                            $i = $i - 7;
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        if ($i == 1) {
                            echo '
                            <div class="latest_post" data-sidebar-position>
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-xl-9">
                                            <!-- Posts-->
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <!-- Post Item-->
                                                <div class="col-12"><a class="card card_type_2" href="'; echo the_permalink() . '">
                                                        <div class="card__container">
                                                            <div class="card__image">'; echo the_post_thumbnail(array(0, 9999), array('class' => 'd-none', 'loading' => 'lazy')) . '</div>
                                                            <div class="card__content">
                                                                <div class="card__post_container">
                                                                    <div class="card__post_name">';  echo the_title() . '</div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div></a></div>
                                                <!-- Post Item-->
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- / Posts-->
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="sidebar_width d-none d-xl-block col-xl-3">
                                            <div class="position-relative"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            ';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        if ($i == 2) {
                            echo '
                            <div class="all_posts">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-xl-9">
                                            <div class="row">';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        if ($i > 1){
                            echo '
                            <!-- Post Item-->
                            <div class="col-6 col-lg-4"><a class="card card_type_1" href="'; echo the_permalink() . '">
                                    <div class="card__container">
                                        <div class="card__image">
                                            <div class="card__image__container">'; echo the_post_thumbnail(array(0, 9999), array('class' => 'd-none', 'loading' => 'lazy')) . '</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card__content">
                                            <div class="card__post_container">
                                                <div class="card__post_container__flex_0">
                                                    <div class="card__post_name">'; echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 15, '...') . '</div>
                                                    <div class="card__post_text">'; echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 75, '...') . '</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="card__post_container__flex_1">
                                                    <div class="card__pseudo_link">Читать</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div></a></div>
                            <!-- Post Item-->
                            ';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        if ($i == 7) {
                            echo '
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            ';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        if ($i == 8) {
                            echo '
                            <div class="latest_post">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-xl-9">
                                            <!-- Posts-->
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <!-- Post Item-->
                                                <div class="col-12"><a class="card card_type_2" href="'; echo the_permalink() . '">
                                                        <div class="card__container">
                                                            <div class="card__image">'; echo the_post_thumbnail(array(0, 9999), array('class' => 'd-none', 'loading' => 'lazy')) . '</div>
                                                            <div class="card__content">
                                                                <div class="card__post_container">
                                                                    <div class="card__post_name">';  echo the_title() . '</div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div></a></div>
                                                <!-- Post Item-->
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- / Posts-->
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="sidebar_width d-none d-xl-block col-xl-3">
                                            <div class="position-relative"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            ';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        if ($i == 9) {
                            echo '
                            <div class="all_posts">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-xl-9">
                                            <div class="row">';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        if ($i > 8){
                            echo '
                            <!-- Post Item-->
                            <div class="col-6 col-lg-4"><a class="card card_type_1" href="'; echo the_permalink() . '">
                                    <div class="card__container">
                                        <div class="card__image">
                                            <div class="card__image__container">'; echo the_post_thumbnail(array(0, 9999), array('class' => 'd-none', 'loading' => 'lazy')) . '</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card__content">
                                            <div class="card__post_container">
                                                <div class="card__post_container__flex_0">
                                                    <div class="card__post_name">'; echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 15, '...') . '</div>
                                                    <div class="card__post_text">'; echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 75, '...') . '</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="card__post_container__flex_1">
                                                    <div class="card__pseudo_link">Читать</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div></a></div>
                            <!-- Post Item-->
                            ';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        if ($i == 14) {
                            echo '
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            ';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
                    <?php bootstrap_pagination(); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: query_posts() предназначена для самого WordPress и должен использоваться для изменения основного Цикла WordPress, если нужно создать еще циклы, то используйте get_posts() или WP_Query. Еще не совсем понятно что должно быть внутри каждого item_post? Это отдельный пост? Если да, то для каждого блока нужно писать свой цикл

Comment: Внутри каждого item_post есть картинка, название, описание и ссылка

Comment: Я поменял пример кода, вот то что я имел ввиду, но теперь появилась другая проблема, это пагинация, когда перехожу на страницу 2 в URL видно что это страница 2, но посты такие-же как и на странице 1 отображаются, и сам блок пагинации выделяет активный пункт как страница 1, хотя в URL все четко

Comment: Не читай больше ГСов. Читай правильную инфу 1. https://wpmag.ru/2014/query_posts-wordpress/ 2. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_WordPress#.D0.9C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.A6.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.BB.D1.8B